# Override values in one Xml file from another

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

Looking for a way to merge to XML files where the modified attributes in the second file should override the values of the objects in the first file. Seems like this should be doable with linq to xml but having some trouble figuring out how to do it.

For example take the following two XML files:

File 1:

```
<root>
   <foo name="1">
     <val1>hello</val1>
     <val2>world</val2>
   </foo>
   <foo name="2">
     <val1>bye</val1>
   </foo>
</root>
```

File 2:

```
<root>
   <foo name="1">
     <val2>friend</val2>
   </foo>
</root>
```

The desired end result would be to merge File 2 in to File 1 and end up with

```
<root>
   <foo name="1">
     <val1>hello</val1>
     <val2>friend</val2>
   </foo>
   <foo name="2">
     <val1>bye</val1>
   </foo>
</root>
```

Sub 'foo' elements should be uniquely identified by their 'name' value with any set values in File 2 overriding the values in File 1.

Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just iterate and update values - don't know how generic you want this to be though...

```
class Program
{
    const string file1 = @"<root><foo name=""1""><val1>hello</val1><val2>world</val2></foo><foo name=""2""><val1>bye</val1></foo></root>";

    const string file2 = @"<root><foo name=""1""><val2>friend</val2></foo></root>";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XDocument document1 = XDocument.Parse(file1);
        XDocument document2 = XDocument.Parse(file2);

        foreach (XElement foo in document2.Descendants("foo"))
        {
            foreach (XElement val in foo.Elements())
            {
                XElement elementToUpdate = (from fooElement in document1.Descendants("foo")
                                            from valElement in fooElement.Elements()
                                            where fooElement.Attribute("name").Value == foo.Attribute("name").Value &&
                                                 valElement.Name == val.Name
                                            select valElement).FirstOrDefault();

                if (elementToUpdate != null)
                    elementToUpdate.Value = val.Value;

            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(document1.ToString());

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build new xml from these two:

```
XDocument xdoc1 = XDocument.Load("file1.xml");
XDocument xdoc2 = XDocument.Load("file2.xml");

XElement root =
    new XElement("root",
        from f in xdoc2.Descendants("foo").Concat(xdoc1.Descendants("foo"))
        group f by (int)f.Attribute("name") into foos
        select new XElement("foo",
            new XAttribute("name", foos.Key),
            foos.Elements().GroupBy(v => v.Name.LocalName)
                           .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
                           .Select(g => g.First())));

root.Save("file1.xml");
```

Thus foo elements from second file selected first, they will have priority over foo elements from first file (when we do grouping).